# How can I stop floated content from pushing down all of the content below?

Tags: css

I'm working on a layout that floats several boxes across multiple rows, and I'm wondering how I can do this in a way that allows each box to float to the top unless there is something above it pushing it down.

At the moment, if the box at the top right is taller than the one on the top left, then both boxes below are pushed down, rather than just the one below the taller box. This results in a strange-looking gap between the top and bottom left boxes.

The boxes will also possibly have varying widths.

Here is a link to a JSFiddle, and for context, below is the actual webpage I'll be applying this layout to.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/t0tmzk0q/3/

**Webpage:** http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work-3/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="module" id="one"></div>
  <div class="module" id="two"></div>
  <div class="module" id="three"></div>
  <div class="module" id="four"></div>
</div>

html,
body {
  height:100%;
  background:pink;
}

.row {
  position:relative;
  width:85%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
} 

.module {
  width:47.5%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:35px;
  background:lightblue;
}

#one.module {
  margin-right:5%;
}

#two.module {
  height:300px;
}

#three.module {
  width:40%;
  margin-right:5%;
}

#four.module {
  width:55%;
}
```

Comment: You can't with `float` like that. You can make a layout like that using css columns http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/ or you can use a plugin like masonry http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: You're looking for what is known as a masonry or Pintrest layout.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll be sure to check that out and see what I can come up with :)